# Does Julia have a way to solve for unknown variables

Tags: excel, julia

Is there a function in Julia that is similar to the solver function in Excel where I can provide and equation, and it will solve for the unknown variable? If not, does anybody know the math behind Excel's solver function? 
I am not expecting anybody to solve the equation, but if it helps:

Price = (Earnings_1/(1+r)^1)+(Earnings_2/(1+r)^2)++(Earnings_3/(1+r)^3)+(Earnings_4/(1+r)^4)+(Earnings_5/(1+r)^5)+(((Earnings_5)*(RiskFreeRate))/((1+r)^5)*(1-RiskFreeRate))

The known variables are: Price, All Earnings, and RiskFreeRate. I am just trying to figure out how to solve for r.

Comment: https://github.com/JuliaOpt/JuMP.jl ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write this instead as an expression `f(r) = 0` by subtracting `Price` over to the other side. Now it's a rootfinding problem. If you only have one variable you're solving for (looks to be the case), then [Roots.jl](https://github.com/JuliaMath/Roots.jl) is a good choice.

```
fzero(f, a::Real, b::Real)
```

will search for a solution between `a` and `b` for example, and the docs have more choices for algorithms when you don't know a range to start with and only give an initial condition for example.

In addition, [KINSOL in Sundials.jl](https://github.com/JuliaDiffEq/Sundials.jl) is good when you know you're starting close to a multidimensional root. For multidimensional and needing some robustness to the initial condition, I'd recommend using [NLsolve.jl](https://github.com/JuliaNLSolvers/NLsolve.jl).

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing out of the box no. Root finding is a science in itself.

Luckily for you, your function has an analytic first derivative with respect to r. That means that you can use Newton Raphson, which will be *extremely* stable for your function.

I'm sure you're aware your function behaves badly around r = -1.

Comment: Julia has a very decentral package ecosystem, but quite coherent. Essentially all functionality is made available in the form of packages, even really basic types such as dataframes. So "out of the box" is not a good descriptor for the availability of something in julia.

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard: That said (and you're the expert her, not me), root finding is such a broad science you always have to get you know your function intimately before deciding on a solution technique. There are some generic algorithms out there that do a good job (e.g. LSGRG used for goalseeking in Microsoft Excel), but a robust general solution is still yet to emerge.